# How to apply same item template within item template?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have employee who has list of employees, so i need to apply the template which will repeat coninuously in a combobox.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid x:Name="grdItem"  
                         Background="Transparent"
                         MouseEnter="grdItem_MouseEnter"
                         MouseLeave="grdItem_MouseLeave" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                        
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"                                                 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Margin="1,0,0,10"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                        ToolTip="{Binding Name}"
                                                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                       />

                    <Popup x:Name="brdSecondary"                     
                                    Placement="Right"
                                    IsOpen="{Binding IsShowFilters}"
                                    Grid.Column="2"   
                                    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}">
                        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                         x:Name="grid1111">

                                <ItemsControl Background="White" x:Name="cmbSoftware1" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
                                                                             KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                       --- USE THE SAME TEMPLATE --
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Can it be done with heirarchial data template? If not how can i acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the leveling in your object model I can think of two solutions:

1. A `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. You have to figure out if the object model supports this though. And by the way, a `ComboBox` does not support a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as far as I know, so you have to put a `TreeView` in as the selecting control.
2. Create a `DataTemplate` resource on a higher level, maybe on `Control` level, and reuse that same `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, can i get a quick small sample template which should show subitems as popup beside it.